# Find which function is being called when a view is clicked

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I have been trying to change what happens when a imageView is clicked in an external library. But I have no idea which function is called when that happens. I really don't want to go through the code and figure it out, so I was wondering, if there was any way I could use something like debugging to figure out which function is called when I click the view?

If it helps, I'm trying to do this: [Issue-2023](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/2023)

Comment: If you want to change what happens, just set a new OnClickListener

Comment: I don't know where the image view is

Comment: Then it's time to go through the code and find its id so you can do a findViewById for it.

Comment: Any way I can do that without going through the code?

Comment: Why do you want to access the specific view? The `MaterialDrawer` uses a `recyclerView` to display the lines, so directly accessing the views is anyways not good, as those are reused

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I'm talking about [issue-2023](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/2023). So, I figured I could set up an on click listener myself if I knew the id for the view.